# What is the best way open/edit a data Stream if all I have is a MIME type

Tags: c#, windows, mime, mime-types

I am in a Windows Desktop application and I have a data stream and a mime type in the database. Is there a better way than writing it to a temp folder and launching the default editor for it?

If I have to use the temp folder how can I get the file extension from the MIME type in a C# Windows Desktop application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookup the MIME type in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type` to find out the corresponding file extension and go from there. Some starter links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147(VS.85).aspx
- http://bitworking.org/news/Atom_Auto_Sub_How_To

If that is not enough, maybe [libmagic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libmagic) (used by the `file` command line tool) or its database can be of use to you, even though it is quite UNIX:y.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with that data stream.  If all you want to do is open the default program for that file type, writing a temp file and calling Process.Start on it isn't a bad way to go.  If you're looking to perform other operations on the data... well, it depends what operations you had in mind.

Comment: However, it would be better if I did not have to save it and invoke a file watcher.